# Wait for Celery task to complete without result backend

Tags: python, celery

With no result backend, how do I wait for a Celery task to complete? Both [`.collect()` and `.get()`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery-result) fail when no result backend is used. I don't need the result of the task, just wait for it to complete.

```
>>> add.delay(1, 2).get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 169, in get
    no_ack=no_ack,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 616, in _is_disabled
    'No result backend configured.  '
NotImplementedError: No result backend configured.  Please see the documentation for more information.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically the task needs to communicate to the client that it is done.

The result backend is the mechanism used by celery to communicate task status. If it is disabled you have to implement your own communication mechanism.

You could set a flag in a store (something lightweight like redis would be good), or the task could write to a shared mount, or you could implement some kind of lightweight web service that both task and client could talk to.

However all of these pretty much duplicate what the result backend does (especially the first suggestion).